# A word to describe a sudden urge to work

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I was wondering if there's a term for a person feeling an unusual drive to be productive, as well as for the feeling itself.

Some example sentences could be:

> - I just drank four cups of coffee, I'm _____, bring it on!
> - Johnny is really excited to start working here. He arrived early and with such a(n) _______.

I'm looking for something such as *psyched*, but relating to work or study, instead of leisure.

As for context, I don't mind it being informal, but I'd like something that doesn't sound demeaning to the subject.

Comment: At least closely connected: [synonym for beginning something eagerly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338797/need-synonym-for-beginning-something-eagerly/338858#338858)

Comment: Perhaps *energized/energy*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

raring to go

> to be ready and excited to begin doing something

[source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raring+to+go)

Comment: Definitely agree with *raring to go*. *Enthused* or *psyched* might also work, but @GEdgar's suggestion sounds like the best fit to me!

Comment: I think this is the best generic expression. For extra enthusiasm, "fired up" or "on fire" could be used..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I liked all answers very much but I'm picking this one because it's a better fit for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

*Champing at the bit* is basically synonymous with *raring to go* - depends if you want a bit of an equine connotation...

See **http://grammarist.com/usage/champing-chomping-at-the-bit/** for more info about *champing* vs *chomping* - either way, definitely has a sense of eagerness to it!

Answer (score 1):

inspired

You don't have to be inspired to want to work, but I certainly find it makes me a lot more interested in buckling down if I am inspired to achieve a goal.